# How to add prerequisite check on .NET Core 5.0.1 in installshield basic MSI project

Tags: .net-core, installshield

I'm going to install a .NET CORE application through installshield. My .NET application has dependency on .NET CORE 5.0.1 So I want to check if .Net core 5.0.1 prerequisite is installed in the system. How can I achieve this in Installshield 2021?

Answer (score 0):

If you search for and use the merge module for .Net Core it will handle all of the checks and install for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following registry value using System search in Installshield and use it in launch condition:

Registry Key:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost

Value: Version